# How to write a C program which creates a file containing unsigned two-byte big-endian integers in the range provided

Tags: c, file, endianness, unsigned

This program is called create_borts_file (bort is a contraction of big-endian short) and takes in:
a filename,
the beginning of a range of integers, and
the end of a range of integers;

This is the code I have so far that creates a file of integers. How would I modify this to get what I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *output_stream = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if (output_stream == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = atoi(argv[2]); i <= atoi(argv[3]); i++) {
        fprintf(output_stream, "%d\n", i);
    }

    fclose(output_stream);

    return 0;
}
```

so that if I were to print the bytes of the file given these arguments it would give the following output:

```
./create_borts_file fortytwo.bort 40 42

./print_bytes fortytwo.bort 
byte    0:   0 0x00
byte    1:  40 0x28 '('
byte    2:   0 0x00
byte    3:  41 0x29 ')'
byte    4:   0 0x00
byte    5:  42 0x2a '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
unsigned short be = htons( (unsigned short)(i & 0xffff) );

size_t err=fwrite(&be,sizeof(be),1,output_stream);
```

Comment: So I have added that to the for loop and used fputc(be, output_stream). The out put is printing extra bytes?
`byte    0:   0 0x00 `
`byte    1:  40 0x28 '('`
`byte    2:   0 0x00 `
`byte    3:   0 0x00 `
`byte    4:  41 0x29 ')'` and so on- pretty much just extra 0 bytes in between each be

Comment: The for loop must have only the two lines written in the answer. No fprintf, no fputc.